# Stretching my content to the footer

Tags: html, css, footer

I kind of have two problems here! I used to be a web designer many years ago, but I've not done much recently - so I've forgotten some of it! I've looked online, I think it's a problem with my code which I'm missing, so I thought I'd see if anyone else can see what I'm doing wrong.

I've tried using the [sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/), but I want to centre the the text in the footer. I've been trying to use padding, but then you have to scroll down to see the footer. How would people recommend I centre the text vertically now?

Also, how do I stretch the content boxes all the way to the footer, regardless of whether there is text in or not? I have attached the HTML and CSS code below. Many thanks in advance!

```css
/* Designed by Allan Wagner */

/* -font-family: 'Bitter', serif;- and -font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;- */

*{margin:0;padding:0;}
body{margin:0;padding:0;background:#EEE;}
html, body{height:100%;}
.wrapper{min-height:100%;margin:0 auto -80px;} /* bottom margin is the negative value of the footers height */

/* Header Left*/
header{margin:0;padding:0;background:#FF4C4F;}
#header-content{margin:0 auto;padding:0;width:960px;overflow:auto;}
#header-left{margin:0;padding:0;float:left;}
#header-title{margin:10px 0;padding:0;font-family:"Montserrat", "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:28px;color:#EEE;text-decoration:none;}
#header-title:hover{color:#FFF;}

/* Header Right */
#header-right{margin:10px 0;padding:0;float:right;}
.searchbar-wrapper{margin:5px 10px;padding:0;float:left;width:440px;}
#searchbar{margin:0 auto;padding:4px;float:left;font-size:20px;border-radius:5px;outline:none;border:#999 thin solid;width:100%;}
#searchbar:hover{outline:none;border:#333 thin solid;}
#searchbar:active{outline:none;border:#000 thin solid;}
nav{margin:8px 10px 0;padding:0;float:right;}
.nav{margin:0 2px 0;padding:5px 10px;float:none;background:#BC2225;border-radius:5px;font-family:"Montserrat", "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;color:#EEE;text-decoration:none;}
.nav:hover{color:#FFF;background:#A11C1E;}

/* Main Content */
#content-wrapper{margin:0 auto;padding:0;float:none;width:960px;height:auto;overflow:visible;}

/* Sidebar */
aside{margin:0;padding:0 10px 10px;background:#BBB;height:auto;width:270px;float:left;overflow:auto;}
.sidebarContainer{margin:10px 0 0 0;padding:0;width:100%;float:left;}
.ul-links{list-style:none;font-family:"Montserrat", "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:400;color:#222;text-decoration:none;}
.li-linklist{padding:0 7px 0;border:none;}
.li-linklist:hover{padding:0 6px 0;border-left:#000 thin solid;}
.li-links{margin:0;padding:0;text-decoration:none;color:#333;}
.li-links:hover{color:#000;}

section{margin:0;padding:0;}
.wSidebar{float:right;width:650px;padding:10px;background:#FFF;overflow:auto;}



/* Footer */
footer, .push{height:80px;clear:both;} /* push must be the same height as footer */
footer{margin:0;padding:20px 0 0;width:100%;background:#FF4C4F;}
.footer-wrapper{margin:0 auto;padding:0;width:960px;height:100%;}
#footer-left{margin:0;padding:0;float:left;}
#footer-right{margin:0;padding:0;float:right;}

/* Text Formatting */
h1{font-family:"Montserrat", "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:22px;}
h2{font-family:"Montserrat", "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:20px;font-weight:400;}
h3{font-family:"Montserrat", "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:400;}

p{font-family:"Bitter", Constantia, "Lucida Bright", "DejaVu Serif", Georgia, serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:400;}
.pstyle{font-family:"Bitter", Constantia, "Lucida Bright", "DejaVu Serif", Georgia, serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:400;}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Home :: Website Name</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter:400,700,400italic|Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href="/styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
 <header>
     <div id="header-content">
         <div id="header-left">
       <h1 id="header-title"><a href="/" id="header-title">Website Name</a></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="searchbar-wrapper">
                <form class="searchbar-wrapper">
                    <input id="searchbar" type="search">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="header-right">
                <nav>
                 <a class="nav" href="/road/">Road</a>
                 <a class="nav" href="/rail/">Rail</a>
                 <a class="nav" href="/air/">Air</a>
                 <a class="nav" href="/sea/">Sea</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="content-wrapper">
     <aside>
         <div class="sidebarContainer">
             <img src="/assets/10646866_863581873661627_2031997718155527748_n (1).jpg" height="40px" width="40px" style="border-radius:20px;float:left;" />
       <div style="float:left;margin:8px 10px 0;"><h2>Hello again, Allan!</h2></div>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebarContainer">
             <h3>Your Profile</h3>
                <ul class="ul-links">
                 <a href="/" class="li-links" ><li class="li-linklist">Timeline Posts</li></a>
                 <a href="/" class="li-links" ><li class="li-linklist">Messages</li></a>
                 <a href="/" class="li-links" ><li class="li-linklist">Notifications</li></a>
                 <a href="/" class="li-links" ><li class="li-linklist">Events</li></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebarContainer">
             <h3>Road Favourites</h3>
                <ul class="ul-links">
                 <a href="/" class="li-links" ><li class="li-linklist">R178 NPN (Volvo B6BLE)</li></a>
                 <a href="/" class="li-links" ><li class="li-linklist">WG65 DDU (ADL Enviro 400)</li></a>
                 <a href="/" class="li-links" ><li class="li-linklist">CK03 TWD (Vauxhall Astra)</li></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebarContainer">
             <h3>Rail Favourites</h3>
                <ul class="ul-links">
                 <a href="/" class="li-links" ><li class="li-linklist">Timeline Posts</li></a>
                 <a href="/" class="li-links" ><li class="li-linklist">Messages</li></a>
                 <a href="/" class="li-links" ><li class="li-linklist">Notifications</li></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
     </aside>
        <section class="wSidebar">
         <h1>Heading 1</h1>
         <h2>Heading 2</h2>
         <h3>Heading 3</h3>
         <h4>Heading 4</h4>
         <h5>Heading 5</h5>
         <h6>Heading 6</h6>
         <p>Paragraph</p>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="push"></div>
<footer>
 <div class="footer-wrapper">
     <div id="footer-left">
         <p>Copyright Information</p>
        </div>
        <div id="footer-right">
         <p>Footer Menu</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

[A screenshot of my webpage on the computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wu4KF.png)

Comment: As far as I remember, you had to decline every parent element an height, beginning from `html`/`body` like `html, body { height: 100%; }`, so the `height` from the content you want to stretch, should become 100%.

Comment: The .push div must be inside of .wrapper div

Answer (score 0):

try this removing push div and clearing footer float

```css
/* Designed by Allan Wagner */

/* -font-family: 'Bitter', serif;- and -font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;- */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #EEE;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -80px;
}
/* bottom margin is the negative value of the footers height */

/* Header Left*/

header {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #FF4C4F;
}
#header-content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 960px;
  overflow: auto;
}
#header-left {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
}
#header-title {
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Montserrat", "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #EEE;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#header-title:hover {
  color: #FFF;
}
/* Header Right */

#header-right {
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
}
.searchbar-wrapper {
  margin: 5px 10px;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  width: 440px;
}
#searchbar {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 4px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  border: #999 thin solid;
  width: 100%;
}
#searchbar:hover {
  outline: none;
  border: #333 thin solid;
}
#searchbar:active {
  outline: none;
  border: #000 thin solid;
}
nav {
  margin: 8px 10px 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
}
.nav {
  margin: 0 2px 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  float: none;
  background: #BC2225;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #EEE;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  background: #A11C1E;
}
/* Main Content */

#content-wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  float: none;
  width: 960px;
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;
}
/* Sidebar */

aside {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 10px 10px;
  background: #BBB;
  height: auto;
  width: 270px;
  float: left;
  overflow: auto;
}
.sidebarContainer {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.ul-links {
  list-style: none;
  font-family: "Montserrat", "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #222;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.li-linklist {
  padding: 0 7px 0;
  border: none;
}
.li-linklist:hover {
  padding: 0 6px 0;
  border-left: #000 thin solid;
}
.li-links {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.li-links:hover {
  color: #000;
}
section {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wSidebar {
  float: right;
  width: 650px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #FFF;
  overflow: auto;
}
/* Footer */

footer,
.push {
  height: 80px;
  clear: both;
}
/* push must be the same height as footer */

footer {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #FF4C4F;
}
.footer-wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 960px;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 40px;
}
#footer-left {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
}
#footer-right {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
  line-height: 40px;
}
/* Text Formatting */

h1 {
  font-family: "Montserrat", "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
}
h2 {
  font-family: "Montserrat", "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
h3 {
  font-family: "Montserrat", "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
p {
  font-family: "Bitter", Constantia, "Lucida Bright", "DejaVu Serif", Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.pstyle {
  font-family: "Bitter", Constantia, "Lucida Bright", "DejaVu Serif", Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Home :: Website Name</title>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter:400,700,400italic|Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
  <link href="/styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>
      <div id="header-content">
        <div id="header-left">
          <h1 id="header-title"><a href="/" id="header-title">Website Name</a></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="searchbar-wrapper">
          <form class="searchbar-wrapper">
            <input id="searchbar" type="search">
          </form>
        </div>
        <div id="header-right">
          <nav>
            <a class="nav" href="/road/">Road</a>
            <a class="nav" href="/rail/">Rail</a>
            <a class="nav" href="/air/">Air</a>
            <a class="nav" href="/sea/">Sea</a>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div id="content-wrapper">
      <aside>
        <div class="sidebarContainer">
          <img src="/assets/10646866_863581873661627_2031997718155527748_n (1).jpg" height="40px" width="40px" style="border-radius:20px;float:left;" />
          <div style="float:left;margin:8px 10px 0;">
            <h2>Hello again, Allan!</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebarContainer">
          <h3>Your Profile</h3>
          <ul class="ul-links">
            <a href="/" class="li-links">
              <li class="li-linklist">Timeline Posts</li>
            </a>
            <a href="/" class="li-links">
              <li class="li-linklist">Messages</li>
            </a>
            <a href="/" class="li-links">
              <li class="li-linklist">Notifications</li>
            </a>
            <a href="/" class="li-links">
              <li class="li-linklist">Events</li>
            </a>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebarContainer">
          <h3>Road Favourites</h3>
          <ul class="ul-links">
            <a href="/" class="li-links">
              <li class="li-linklist">R178 NPN (Volvo B6BLE)</li>
            </a>
            <a href="/" class="li-links">
              <li class="li-linklist">WG65 DDU (ADL Enviro 400)</li>
            </a>
            <a href="/" class="li-links">
              <li class="li-linklist">CK03 TWD (Vauxhall Astra)</li>
            </a>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebarContainer">
          <h3>Rail Favourites</h3>
          <ul class="ul-links">
            <a href="/" class="li-links">
              <li class="li-linklist">Timeline Posts</li>
            </a>
            <a href="/" class="li-links">
              <li class="li-linklist">Messages</li>
            </a>
            <a href="/" class="li-links">
              <li class="li-linklist">Notifications</li>
            </a>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </aside>
      <section class="wSidebar">
        <h1>Heading 1</h1>
        <h2>Heading 2</h2>
        <h3>Heading 3</h3>
        <h4>Heading 4</h4>
        <h5>Heading 5</h5>
        <h6>Heading 6</h6>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  <footer>
    <div class="footer-wrapper">
      <div id="footer-left">
        <p>Copyright Information</p>
      </div>
      <div id="footer-right">
        <p>Footer Menu</p>
      </div>
      <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/61jdyxqu/2/

Css:

```
/* general layout settings */
* {
    margin:0;
}

html, body {
    height:100%;
}

.wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    height:auto !important; 
    height:100%;
    margin:0 auto -80px; 
}

.footer, .push {
    height:80px; 
}

.header-wrapper,
.content-wrapper,
.footer-wrapper{
    width:960px;
}

.header-wrapper:after,
.content-wrapper:after,
.footer-wrapper:after{
    content:"";
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}

.header .left-content,
.header .center-content,
.content .left-content,
.content .center-content,
.footer .left-content,
.footer .center-content{
    float:left;
}


.header .left-content,
.content .left-content,
.footer .left-content{
    width:250px;
}


.header .center-content,
.content .center-content,
.footer .center-content{
    width:710px;
}

/**/
```

Html:

```
<!-- Page -->
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="header-wrapper">
            <div class="header-content">
            <div class="left-content">Logo</div>
            <div class="center-content">Menu</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="left-content">Aside</div>
            <div class="center-content">Content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="push"></div>
</div>

<!-- Footer -->
<div class="footer">
    <div class="footer-wrapper">
        <div class="footer-content">
            <div class="left-content">Copyright</div>
            <div class="center-content">2015</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```